# How to replace xml tag value using xmlstarlet command?

Tags: xml, bash, cdata, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to change a tag value in xml using sed command. I also used xmlstarlet as well but didn't help because of CDATA tag. Below is the tag.

xmlstarlet changes `<>` to `&gt;` and `&lt;` respectively.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//item[@name]/val' -v '<![CDATA[1234]]>' file.xml
```

output:

```
  <item name="Rx_Frequency">
    <val>&lt;\![CDATA[1234]]&gt;</val>
  </item>
```

sample input

```
<item name="Rx_Frequency">
    <val><![CDATA[xxx]]></val>
</item>
```

expected output:

```
<item name="Rx_Frequency">
    <val><![CDATA[1234]]></val>
</item>
```

Comment: Add your attempted code to your question in code blocks.

Comment: I edited his post myself, because I fails like him with HTML entities conversion

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet`. I assume your file does not use [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-namespaces/info).

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
  --update '//item[@name]/val' --value '<![CDATA[1234]]>' file.xml | xmlstarlet unescape
```

Output:

```
<item name="Rx_Frequency">
  <val><![CDATA[1234]]></val>
</item>
```

See: `xmlstarlet unescape --help`

Answer (score 1):

`xmllint`can be used too

```
printf '%s\n' 'cd //item[@name]/val' 'set <![CDATA[1234]]>' 'save' 'bye' | xmllint --shell tmp.xml
```

Command output

```
/ > cd //item[@name]/val
val > set <![CDATA[1234]]>
val > save
val > bye
```

Result

```
<item name="Rx_Frequency">
    <val><![CDATA[1234]]></val>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NB**: This is a crude hack, not a recommendation.

`xmlstarlet edit` accepts irregular element names (it's not an XSLT
processor) so it's possible to create a `CDATA` section by inserting
an empty element with a strange name and have `sed` fix up the
section's end marker:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '<doc><v>x</v></doc>' |
xmlstarlet edit -O -P \
  --var T '*/*' \
  -d '$T/text()' \
  -s '$T' -t elem -n '![CDATA[1234&nbsp;<"'\''>]]' -v '' |
sed 's,]]/>,]]>,g'
```

Output:

```xml
<doc><v><![CDATA[1234&nbsp;<"'>]]></v></doc>
```

Since `]]/>` can occur in a `CDATA` section in the XML input the safe
approach would be to make sure it does not already exist.